# Sqflite database integration giving error

Tags: dart, flutter, sqflite

```
I am working integrating SQFLite plugin in a flutter. For the first time table is created and everything is working but when I try to open the database for the second time for running query it gives me a sqflite error.

<code>
Future<Database> initializeDatabase() async {
    io.Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, databaseName);
    Database database = await openDatabase(
      path,
      version: 1,
      onCreate: (Database db, int newVersion) async {
        await db.execute(
          '''
        CREATE TABLE $tableName(ss INTEGER , dd TEXT, uu TEXT)''',
        );
        print("Created tables");
      },
    );
    return database;
  }



insert() async {
    Database db = await database;
    var id = await db.insert(
      tableName,
      {
        'ss': 1,
        'dd': "sdsds",
        'uu': "vvvvvvv",
      },
    );
    return id;
    // await db.close();
  }

</code>
```

For the first insert query everything works fine but the second time it gives following errors:-
Error:-
Error calling sqlite3_step (1: cannot rollback - no transaction is active) SQLITE_ERROR
DB Query: ROLLBACK
Unknown error finalizing or resetting statement (1: cannot rollback - no transaction is active)
DB Query: ROLLBACK

Comment: How are you getting the database in each method? The part in which you do await database

Comment: Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database;
    _database = await initializeDatabase();
    return _database;
  }